# Installing spaCy on OSX causes sslError (TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION)

Tags: python, macos, spacy

I'm trying to install Spacy, but I'm having this SSL error, I already tried different solutions in fixing, but I still can't find a way to run pass this SSL error.

Known issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue18378

Versions

```
(witty_env) ➜  moodie pip --version
pythpip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

(witty_env) ➜  moodie python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

---

````
(witty_env) ➜  moodie LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 python -m spacy download en                                              

Collecting https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)
(witty_env) ➜  moodie```
````

Comment: As of now, my only solution was to switch to Python 3.x.x and Spacy installation was ok.

Comment: I think this is because of **deprecation of TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 support by GitHub** in February 2018. See https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/